# custom ML Kit in react native

Tags: react-native, firebase-mlkit

Custom model support is not there in https://rnfirebase.io/

Does nay other project support ML Kit on custom model?

Answer (score 0):

ML Kit may not have support for React Native in Custom Model, please consider to use TFLite directly.

There are a couple of projects doing it, for example:
https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=react%20native%20tensorflow%20lite